# Замедлить выполнения скрипта jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой скрипт

```
function submitFilter(){
    form= $("form[name=filterForm]");
    form.find("[name=page]").val(0);
    data= form.serialize();
    $(".cap").css({display:"block"});
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: data,
        success: function(answer) {
            $(".blockContent").empty();
            $(".blockContent").append(answer);
            $(".cap").css({display:"none"});
        }
    });
}
```

Между  $(".cap").css({display:"block"}); и $(".cap").css({display:"none"}); проходит мало времени и я не успеваю увидеть лоадер. Можно какнибудь поставить таймер или замедлить хотя бы на 1 секунду, что бы успевать увидеть лоадер.

Comment: Зачем это нужно? Раз быстро загружаются/обрабатываются данные, значит все отлично работает, без тормозов.

Comment: ну тут больше для того что бы пользователь видел что данные подгрузились, а то такой эффект он даже не понимает что была загрузка

Comment: @duddeniska намеренно делать загрузку данных дольше, чтоб юзер увидел лоадер, в то время, как все борятся за скоростя - вы извращенец сэр))  .....а при соц сети будете эмулировать большую работу БД тоже?) чтоб страничка грузилась секунду две)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var timeout;

function submitFilter(){
    form= $("form[name=filterForm]");
    form.find("[name=page]").val(0);
    data= form.serialize();
    $(".cap").css({display:"block"});
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: data,
        success: function(answer) {
            $(".blockContent").empty();
            $(".blockContent").append(answer);
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                $(".cap").css({display:"none"});
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout - именно то что вам нужно

```
form= $("form[name=filterForm]");
form.find("[name=page]").val(0);
data= form.serialize();
$(".cap").css({display:"block"});
setTimeout(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: data,
        success: function(answer) {
            $(".blockContent").empty();
            $(".blockContent").append(answer);
            $(".cap").css({display:"none"});
        }
    });
}, 2000);
```